# Why JQuery's load() isn't working?

Tags: jquery, preloading

Hi everyone
in my main html file, I have this div that some img are define in it:

```
< div id="preload">
    < img src="http://howindia.com/......jpg" width="1" height="1" /> 
< /div>
```

and in my .js file I said:

```
$("#preload").load(function(){
    alert("something...");
    //call other functions 
});
```

but simply loading all images into the < div id="preload"> won't trigger any event and

Comment: Oh, I do love a good question cliffhanger! "and..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image load event does not propagate to the div. Try adding a load handler to the image(s) instead.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYnFn/)

```
$("#preload img").load(function(){
    alert("something...");
    //call other functions 
});
```

Comment: also be sure that code is called after the DOM is loaded, inside `$(function(){ ... })`

Comment: @Luca Matteis or put scripts before closing body tag!

Answer (score 1):

First off, a quick tip. If a library used by thousands (millions?) of people was "not working" chances are it wouldn't be you who noticed it. Its 100% more likely in this situation that it's your code not working, not jQuery.

As for your issue, a quick look at the [documentation for load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) shows no overload taking a function as the first parameter. It is defined as:

```
.load( url, [ data ], [ complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )
```

Are you maybe really trying to use [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Or perhaps the [`.load()` event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), in which case the documentation specifies

> The load event is sent to an element
>   when it and all sub-elements have been
>   completely loaded. This event can be
>   sent to any element associated with a
>   URL: **images, scripts, frames, iframes,
>   and the window object**.

Comment: I believe the OP was talking about image load events rather than the jquery xhr .load, although it is hard to be 100% sure:)

Comment: @redsquare - you might be right. I didnt consider that. Answer editied.

Comment: yeah... by "it's not working" i meant "it's not working for me or my purpose" or in other word "i don't know how to use it"

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // do what u want.
});
```